Minimising finite-dimensional problem.
I am trying to find the gradient of the function
$\Psi(x) = \| A x - b \|^2$,
where $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$ and $\mathbb{K}$ is the field of real or complex numbers.
I began by noting that
$$\Psi(x) = \| A x - b \|^2 = (A x - b)^* (A x - b),$$
where $(\cdot)^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose.
Next, I observed that:
$$(A x - b)^* = (A x)^* - b^* = x^* A^* - b^*.$$
Expanding $\| A x - b \|^2$, we get:
$$\| A x - b \|^2 = (A x - b)^* (A x - b) = x^* A^* A x - x^* A^* b - b^* A x + b^* b.$$
To compute the gradient $\nabla_x \Psi(x)$, I apply the gradient operator $\nabla_x$ to each term:
$$\nabla_x \left( x^* A^* A x - x^* A^* b - b^* A x \right).$$
At this stage, I am unsure how to evaluate the gradients of these terms explicitly.

You can use the following trick using the definition of a differential $D_\Psi(\delta_x) = \nabla \Psi^* \delta x$ : $\Psi(x + \delta x) - \Psi(x) = (A(x+\delta x)-b)^*(A(x + \delta x) - b) - (Ax-b)^*(Ax - b) = (Ax+A\delta x-b)^*(Ax + A\delta x - b) - (Ax-b)^*(Ax - b)=(x^*A^*Ax + x^*A^* A\delta x - x^*A^*b + \delta x^*A^*Ax + \delta x^*A^*A \delta x - \delta x^*A^* b - b^* Ax - b^* A \delta x + b^*b) - (x^*A^*Ax - x^*A^*  b - b^* Ax + b^*b) = x^*A^* A\delta x - b^* A \delta x + \delta x^*A^*Ax - \delta x^*A^*Ax b + \delta x^*A^*A \delta x = (2 x^*A^* A - 2 b^* A) \delta x + O(\|\delta x\|^2)$ so we have $\nabla \Psi = 2(Ax - b)^*A$
